# Socket -> Connection refused issue

Tags: sockets, socketexception

I'm having an issue with Sockets and i can't resolve the problem.

I have 2 distincts machines on the same network. I try to send an object from the first machine to the second.

The second machine is the server, a thread that open a ServerSocket on the port 1456 is running on it. I call the accept() method and it seems to work fine.

When I try to connect to the server from the first machine I receive a ConnectException, Connection refused.

I did a lot of research and found that the port i'm trying to connect to is probably close (firewall issue). I found that the antivirus "avast" blocks the port, so I disable the antivirus and it worked fine ! For 5min...

I uninstalled the antivirus and then it became impossible again to connect to the server. I disabled the windows firewall on both machines. I restarted the machines after each actions.

Does someone have an idea about that?

thanks.

Comment: Can you even ping the server from your client machine?

Comment: Can you successfully `telnet` to port 1456 running the telnet client on the server machine?  This will tell you if your software is indeed listening on port 1456.  Since your server is running Windows, you can also run the command `netstat -ano` which will list out all ports that are being listened on and show the PID (process ID) of the process that is performing the listen, which for port 1456 should be your program.

Comment: yes i can ping the server, i can also connect to a distant database located on the server. I tried the netstat -ano (running on XP), but the port 1456 isn't in the list... what i don't understand.

This is my code : 

 System.out.println("En attente de connexions clients...");
client = getServer().accept();

The print is well done, and the accept method seems to be good since i don't have any error.

Comment: Well it seems i didn't look at the right place, I found that line in the netstat window:

TCP 0.0.0.0:1456 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 460

And 460 is my java process.

And i still can't connect to the server via this port.